# Инициализация std::array круглыми скобками

Tags: c++, массивы, инициализация

```
struct A {
    int x, y, z;
} a = A(1, 2, 3);

#include <array>
auto b = std::array<int,3>(1, 2, 3);
```

> [error: array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:37,endLineNumber:6,positionColumn:37,positionLineNumber:6,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:%27struct+A+%7B%0A++++int+x,+y,+z%3B%0A%7D+a+%3D+A(1,+2,+3)%3B%0A%0A%23include+%3Carray%3E%0Aauto+b+%3D+std::array%3Cint,3%3E(1,+2,+3)%3B%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Почему можно инициализировать структуру с помощью такого синтаксиса, а `std::array`, который является структурной обёрткой над C-массивом, нельзя?

Comment: А вы пробовали инициализировать **массив** в круглых скобках?

Comment: @Harry С-массив не класс, поэтому там нельзя использовать круглые скобки в любом случае, но `std::array` ведь класс

Comment: Ну у меня и на структуру пишет ошибку при такой инициализации. Т.к. требуется конструктор с тремя аргументами, а по-умолчанию есть 3 конструктора - без аргументов `A::A()`, конструктор копирования `A::A(A&)` и move-конструктор `A::A(A&&)`.

Comment: @DmitryK по ссылке нет ошибки для 1-ого случая. Возможно, вы не добавили флаг указания стандарта выше 20-ого

Comment: поигрался с компиляторами в `compiler explorer` - gcc позволяет так инициализировать структуру, а clang - нет. Но вообще правильно через фигурные скобки - `A a{1, 2, 3};` с флагом с++20

Comment: И что, у этого *класса* есть конструктор от трех `int`ов?

Answer (score 4):

До С++20 оба варианта работали только с фигурными скобками: `A{1, 2, 3}` и `std::array<int,3>{1, 2, 3}` соответственно.

С первой записью все понятно, а вот вторая является сокращением от `std::array<int,3>{{1, 2, 3}}`. `std::array` - это структура с единственным полем-массивом (с неизвестным именем), поэтому одна пара скобок - для всей структуры, а вторая - для этого массива.

С++20 разрешил инициализацию *агрегатов* круглыми скобками. Агрегат (aggregate) - это структура без (самописных) конструкторов, либо массив.

Поэтому первая запись заработала с круглыми скобками. А про вторую читаем [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization):

> [круглые скобки ведут себя] as described in [aggregate initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) except that ... there is no brace elision

Т.е. круглые скобки, в отличие от фигурных, не разрешают убирать лишние (фигурные) скобки.

И вроде бы это означает, что можно писать `std::array<int,3>({1, 2, 3})`. Но соль в том, что эта запись работала и в более ранних версиях, поскольку являлалсь сокращением от `std::array<int,3>(std::array<int,3>{1, 2, 3})`. По идее, сейчас она должна вместо этого разворачиваться в `std::array<int,3>{{1, 2, 3}}`, но как заметить разницу, и есть ли она вообще - непонятно.

---

В комментариях заметили, что в кланге и первая запись не компилируется. Они, редиски, до сих пор не поддержали инициализацию агрегатов круглыми скобками.